# Quiero traer solo los registros de un mes especifico pero no encuentro la manera

Tags: nodejs, typescript

la consulta no funciona, no trae el mes que se le indica, esto es desde el backend...
he tratado de hacerla de diferentes maneras pero ninguna funciona, no se si estoy pasando algo por alto o simplemente esta errado mi codigo

````
    const { mes } = req.params;
    const clientRepository = getRepository(Cliente);

    let client;

    try {
     
       client = await clientRepository.find({ order: {id: 'DESC'}, where: { fechaVenta: mes }, take: 10});
      

      if (client && client?.length > 0) {
    
        res.send(client);
      } else {
      
       
        res.status(404).json({ message: "No hay resultados" });
      }
    } catch (e) {
     
      res.status(404).json({ message: "Algo ha ido mal" });
    }
  }; ```
````

Comment: ¿Has hecho debug de la variable `mes`? Porque el código se ve bien a simple vista. Deberías hacer un `console.log(mes)`. Por otro lado, dices que no trae el mes que debería, ¿puedes poner un ejemplo del mes que pides y el mes que te devuelve? ¿La variable `mes`, de qué tipo es?

Comment: `client?.length` ¿Qué sentido tiene el signo `?`?

Comment: @FranciscoJavier es [encadenamiento opcional](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: Gracias, @padaleiana, lo desconocía. Así que sirve para controlar posibles errores por variables no asignadas, etc. Supongo.

Comment: El caso esta en que cuando trato de traer los valores ya almacenados, no los trae, la variable funciona bien solo que no se como traer el rango, los 30 dias de un mes, porque no solo termina alli, luego hay que hacer unas especificaciones adicionales dentro del mismo codigo asi que no esta completo, si quito el where: si funciona, traer todos los datos. Pero quiero traer todos los valores ya sea enero, febrero, abril.... expresado en numero(1,2,3...). pero no se si me haga falta determinar el año tambien!

Comment: Falta revisar el código de `clientRepository`. ¿Qué base de datos usas? El código que muestras es insuficiente. Saludos

Comment: Trabajo con mysql... entidades creadas en node.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra _en_ la pregunta el resultado que estás obteniendo y el que querrías obtener. Es más fácil entender el problema con un ejemplo.